# Sum rows and columns of DataFrame with MultiIndex

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, tuples, multi-index

I'm trying to write a function that takes a 2D square DataFrame and a list of indexes as input, and returns a new DataFrame with the sum of row and column indexes.
Here the code with an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def cluster_sum(matrix, cluster):

    matrix[tuple(cluster)] = matrix[cluster].sum(axis=1)
    matrix = matrix.drop(cluster, axis=1)
    matrix = matrix.append(pd.Series(matrix.loc[cluster, :].sum(axis=0), name=tuple(cluster)))
    matrix = matrix.drop(cluster, axis=0)

    return matrix

idx = ['a', 'b', 'c']
sample_df = pd.DataFrame(np.array([[0, 1, 1], [1, 0, 1], [1, 1, 0]]), index=idx, columns=idx)
print(sample_df)
```

Current DataFrame:

```
   a  b  c
a  0  1  1
b  1  0  1
c  1  1  0
```

I define a cluster and apply cluster_sum:

```
cluster = ['a', 'b']

new_df = cluster_sum(sample_df, cluster)
print(new_df)
```

The result is what I expected it to be:

```
        c  (a, b)
c       0       2
(a, b)  2       2
```

Now here comes the problem: if I try to select the new row (a, b):
`print(new_df.loc[('a', 'b'), :])`
it gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\logistic-tool\try2.py", line 23, in <module>
    print(new_df.loc[('a', 'b'), :])
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\print\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 925, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_tuple(key)
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\print\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1109, in _getitem_tuple
    return self._getitem_tuple_same_dim(tup)
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\print\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 806, in _getitem_tuple_same_dim
    retval = getattr(retval, self.name)._getitem_axis(key, axis=i)
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\print\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1153, in _getitem_axis
    return self._getitem_iterable(key, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\print\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1093, in _getitem_iterable
    keyarr, indexer = self._get_listlike_indexer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\print\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1314, in _get_listlike_indexer
    self._validate_read_indexer(keyarr, indexer, axis)
  File "C:\Users\damia\PycharmProjects\print\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1374, in _validate_read_indexer
    raise KeyError(f"None of [{key}] are in the [{axis_name}]")
KeyError: "None of [Index(['a', 'b'], dtype='object')] are in the [index]"
```

I have done some research and i'm sure that the problem is the index in the form of a tuple. I think that pandas wants me to use a MultiIndex in the new row, and probably it would be best to use Multi Index also in the column, but I'm not familiar with MultiIndex. I tried to create a Series with a MultiIndex name and then add it to the DataFrame, but I don't think it's possible to create a MultiIndex Series, so here I am asking for suggestions.

Edit: putting the index inside square brackets, like that: `new_df.loc[[('a', 'b')], :]`
is not a good solution for me, because I would need to check if the index is a tuple or not, which is not an efficent solution. Something like this:

```
for i in new_df.index:
    if type(i) is tuple:
        print(new_df.loc[[i], :])
    else:
        print(new_df.loc[i, :])
```

It would work but there must be a more efficent solution...

Comment: can the list of indices (`cluster`) be more than 2 items long?  You mention `MultiIndex` in the question; if the cluster size can be more than 2, or if you intend to run this more than once, neither your current approach or any alternate implementation with `MultiIndex` can be `if..else` free (as then various rows will have arbitrary depth index). A bit more clarification on the context could be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

To select the tuple index, put `("a", "b")` inside `[ ]`:

```py
print(new_df.loc[[("a", "b")], :])
```

Prints:

```
        c  (a, b)
(a, b)  2       2
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but the point is that to do this I would need to know if a certain index is a tuple or not, and this is a problem if I want to iterate over the dataframe indexes. If I want to use a for loop over n indexes (the matrix can be of any length, this one is just an example) I would need to add an if statement to check if the type of the index is tuple or not. There must be a more efficent way!